# Show inclusion and embedding

Tags: distribution-theory

I am looking at the following theorem:

- $C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the embedding is continuous.
- $C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$
- $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the embedding is continuous.

Note that a function $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for which $||\phi||_{\alpha, \beta}=\sup_x |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta} \phi|<+\infty \ \ \ \forall \alpha, \beta$ belongs to $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

- Let $\phi \in C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We have that $supp (D^{\beta} \phi) \subset supp(\phi)$ since $D^{\beta} \phi \neq 0 \Rightarrow \phi \neq 0$, right? From this we have that $D^{\beta}\phi \in C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, thus also $x^{\alpha} D^{\beta} \phi \in C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n), \forall \alpha$. And so we deduce that $\sup_x |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta} \phi|<+\infty \Rightarrow \phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

  Right? But how can we show that the embedding is continuous?
- Let $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Let $\rho(x)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rho(x) dx=1, \ \ \ supp{\rho } \subset \{ ||x|| \leq 1\}$ . Consider $\phi_j(x)=\rho{\left( \frac{x}{j}\right)} \phi(x) \in C_C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

  So it suffices to show that $\phi_j(x) \to\phi(x)$. How could we show this?

  - Let $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $ \sup_x |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta}\phi |<+\infty$ . For $\alpha=0, \beta=0$ we get that $\sup_x|\phi|<+\infty$. So $\int |\phi(x)| dx<+\infty$ and so $\phi \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is this right? How can we show that the embedding is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

While $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ fails to be first countable, it is still true that for any linear map $T: C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n) \to X$ where $X$ is a topological vector space whose topology is induced by a family seminorms (i.e., a locally convex TVS), we have that $T$ is continuous iff $T$ is sequentially continuous. It's immediate that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n) \subset S(\mathbb R^n)$; to prove that the embedding is continuous to need to prove that the inclusion map $\iota: C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)\to S(\mathbb R^n)$ is continuous. I brought up the first point, because it is easiest to prove the inclusion map is sequentially continuous. To do this, take a sequence $\{f_k\}$ in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ converging to $f \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ and prove that this implies that $f_k \to f$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$. Depending on how you define the topology on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$, this is actually fairly trivial.

On the second point, you're on the right track. I'm not sure it is important for $\rho$ to integrate to $1$. Instead, I would take a sequence $\{ \rho_k\}$ in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\rho_k = 1$ on $[-k,k]^n$ and $\rho = 0$ outside of $[-(k+1),k+1]^n$. Then for any $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^n)$, we should have $\phi \cdot \rho_k \to \phi$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ and each $\phi \cdot \rho_k$ is in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$.

For the last part, again it is clear that $S(\mathbb R^n) \subset L^1(\mathbb R^n)$. To prove the embedding is continuous, you need to prove that if $f_k \to f$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ then $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$. This should be fairly clear because the Schwartz topology is very strong.

I can type up a solution to the 3rd one as an example, if necessary.

EDIT: To answer questions from the comments. To show that $f_k \to f$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$, you need to show that for every multi-indices $\alpha, \beta$ we have $x^\alpha D^\beta f_k \to x^\beta \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R^n$.

The reason $\phi \cdot \rho_k \to \phi$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ is because $\rho_k$ doesn't change $\phi$ on $[-k,k]^n$ and outside of $[-k,k]^n$ (as $k$ gets large) $\phi$ and all of its derivatives decay rapidly to zero.

I think your justification is fine. No, you need to prove something stronger: you need to prove that if $x^\alpha D^\beta f_k \to x^\beta \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R^n$ for all multi-indices $\alpha, \beta$, then $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \lvert f_k(x) - f(x) \rvert dx \to 0$. Proving that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \lvert f_k(x) - f(x) \rvert dx < +\infty$ is not strong enough.

Comment: For the first part, could you explain to me how we can show that $f_k \to f$ in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ? $$$$  For the second part, why does it hold that $\phi \cdot \rho_k \to \phi$ in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?  $$$$
For the last part, is my justification why $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ right?  In order to show that the embedding is continuous, to we have to show that if $\sup_x |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta}(f_k-f)|<+\infty$ then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (f_k-f) dx<+\infty$ ? Do we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? If so , how?

Comment: To show that $f_k \to f$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$, you need to show that for every multi-indices $\alpha, \beta$ we have $x^\beta \partial^\alpha f_k \to x^\beta \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I realized I wouldn't be able to answer these in a comment so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must know continuous immersion in locally convex spaces, in this case we can also speak of Fréchet spaces for $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, instead $C_{c}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a LCS. Precisely theorem (1) of this question:  [Continuous inclusions in locally convex spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537737/continuous-inclusions-in-locally-convex-spaces/1672209#1672209)

The problem is that you have to consider the appropriate topologies.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me what we have to do? I haven't seen a similar proof. @JohnMartin

Comment: @Evinda you understand what is a continued inclusion between locally convex spaces?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't heard of locally convex spaces before. @JohnMartin

Comment: But you know how the topology defined in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? the continuous inclusion between LCS are characterized as a particular case of Theorem 1, of the previous link. If you understand this, I can answer you. @Evinda

Comment: I have just seen the definition of $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: The point is that the proof of such continuous inclusions using that theorem in the link, which generalizzaziona the condition of continuity of linear operators between LCS. If you accept this theorem, I can answer you @Evinda